# AutoLayout fill width of UIViewController

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to get a UIView to fill the width of my `UIViewController` I've set the constraints as follows
[image: constraints]

and I'm getting a layout as follows in IB 
[image]

What am I supposed to be setting to remove the margins on the view? I have a scrollview which I'm happen to have the margins on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use left margin and equal width constraints but that could be taste. The other way would be to use a trailing constraint.

You can remove the margin in your constraint options. Otherwise you have to set it to -16 or something like that

[image: Constraints]

[image: leading constraint]

[image: margin options]

Comment: Just so its clear `Relative to margin` was ticked, unticking it and setting the width to be equal to the container fixed the issue, why have Apple hidden these options

Comment: You can just select both views and use the 'Align trailing' and 'Align leading' shortcuts. The resulting constraints are the same.

Answer (score 1):

It show that you have given constraints with margin. To avoid constraint with margin you can uncheck checkbox...

[image]